# Any way to add launch flags to an Intent Preference XML?

Tags: android, preferences

I want to use an Intent Preference to launch a simple activity. There are 
many examples of how to do this even using extra data e.g.

```
<header
    android:title="@string/title"
    android:id="@+id/pref"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" >
    <intent
         android:action="com.name.intent.action.VIEW_SETTINGS" >
        <extra android:name="name" android:value="value" />
    </intent>
</header>
```

However, I want to use launch flags like in the following code:

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

I could not find an example for adding the launch flags in XML. Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to set the flags from XML. You can see this in the source code - the parseIntent() method in Intent.java.

If you are making a live wallpaper you can get part of the solution by setting the launchMode of the settings activity to singleInstance in the manifest.